# Using where based on relationships with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to filter users based on `with()` relationship. By filter, I mean do not return that user at all.

```
User::with('info');
```

This works for returning the "info" relationship.

---

Now I want to query based on.

- `where('info.allowance', null);`

---

If I try this:

```
User::with(['info' => function($q) {
   return $q->where('allowance', '>', 0);
})
```

... it returns all the users but only the "info" model for the users that has allowance > 0. This is not what I want.

What I want: return only the users that has allowance > 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `whereHas()` method:

```
User::with(['info' => function($q) {
  return $q->where('allowance', '>', 0);
})->whereHas('info', function($q) {
  return $q->where('allowance', '>', 0);
})->get();
```

`->with()` is for eager-loading, so each instance of `$user->info` will be constrained to the logic passed, but `->whereHas()` constrains the original query, so it'll return only `User` records that match the given logic.

Sidenote, it looks odd that you use the same clause for both, but you can (and in this case should).

Comment: and you can save that anonymous function to a variable and use that variable as the second argument to `whereHas` to not have to rewrite it

Comment: `...with(['info' => $func = function ($q) { ... })->whereHas('info', $func)->get();`